# array of size 1 MB

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

```
#include<iostream>
#include <intrin.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned __int64 TimeValue=0;

unsigned __int64 rdtsc(void) 
{  
   return __rdtsc(); 
};

void time_start() { TimeValue=rdtsc(); }
long long time_stop() { 
    return (rdtsc()-TimeValue); 
}
int main()
{
    long x[262144],i,k,r;
    int j;
    x[0] = 0;
for (i=1; i<262144; i++)
{
    long r = rand()%i;
    x[i] = x[r];
    x[r] = i;
}
    time_start();
    for (j=0; j<1000; j++)
        for (k=0, i=0; i<262144; i++) 
            k = x[k];
    cout<<time_stop()/1000/262144;
}
```

In the program I need to create an array size of 1 megabyte. When debugging a program on the line `long x [262144]`, an error occurs: An unhandled exception "0x00ff1997" in the "dgdxgdrfy.exe": 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow. Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: try declaring your array as global.

Answer (score 3):

Try to declare it as a global variable - outside the `main` method(). Otherwise it will be allocated on the stack which is far smaller than the heap. Another solution is to use dynamic allocation with `new`, but this is more error prone.

Comment: If you use `new`, use it with a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`). Better yet, use `std::vector`.

Comment: A global variable might work in this specific example, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you, offer an array of global variable has really helped.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables get allocated on the stack, but the stack is limited. You can probably increase the limit with a switch on the compiler.

The problem is the very large array you've declared. One simple fix will change it from being on the stack to being dynamically allocated:

```
std::vector<long> x(262144);
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because a local array is allocated on the stack. You can avoid this by using a dynamic array(one created with new), a vector or by declaring the array in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static long x[262144]`; It does move the allocation outside the stack and you don't modify your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should dynamically allocate the x array, as is seen in [this article](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/11/23/memory-management-2.html). The below example was pulled out from the text, if you change it to be appropriate for your case, it should work fine.

```
double *num; 
num = (double *) malloc (BUFSZ* sizeof(double))
```

Comment: Why `malloc` when we have `new`?

Comment: @PetarMinchev: The example was C specific, but any form of dynamic allocation should do...